# Set and show multiplicity in Eclipse UML Class Diagram

Tags: eclipse, uml

I'm wondering how to set the multiplicity of an association on a Class Diagram made with Eclipse UML 2.1 — I can see "lower" and "upper" properties, but the values don't appear on the diagram. Furthermore, it seems I can only use finite values.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just modify the label "dst" or "src" with "dst [0..*]" for instance.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2Tools_FAQ#How_can_I_change_multiplicity_of_an_Association_End.3F